# Gmail Message to Twilio SMS

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, twilio

I am trying to find a way to take a message in the inbox of a specific Gmail account and convert it to an SMS via Twilio. Is anyone aware of any resources/Google Applications Script for doing this?

Comment: Twilio has a REST API you could access with Google Apps Script's `HtmlService`.

Comment: Are you aware of any examples of code for this? My knowledge on this is really limited, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Twilio-gas](https://github.com/illiatdesdindes/twilio-gas), a Google Apps Script library for sending SMS messages via Twilio. There is some example code there.